# How to know that two quantum states are the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

It's is maybe a silly question, but I'm getting confused always.
In order to explain what I mean, I will give a simple example:

Let's assume we got one-dimensional potential well in length of $L$ , so the solution for the TIE of schrodinger is:
$$\phi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{L}{2}}sin(kx)$$ where

$k=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}=\frac{2\pi n}{L} $  and $n=1,2,3..$

My question is why for negative $n$, I will have the same state as for $-n$?

I see that the energies are the same, but that is not an explanation, because the are contradicts.

$\phi(x)$ is not the same, but the probability for getting the states are the same.

In other words how I decide the $n$ range?

Comment: The state $-n$ is just the same as the state $n$, since they differ by only a minus sign.

Comment: you are saying that minus sigh does not impact the  state, why is that? that's is maybe  involves the definition of state?

Comment: Yes, they are the same by definition. This should be intuitive: would you believe a salesperson saying the guitar they're selling you really has 12 strings, because you can pluck each of the 6 strings backwards too? It's the same note either way.

Comment: Perhaps you could perform an interference experiment and that would tell you if they are indeed the same or different?

Answer (score 2):

$\psi(x) \rightarrow -\psi(x) = e^{i\pi}\psi(x) $

is just an overall phase factor--and you are free to choose that: it is not an observable.

Answer (score 2):

Because ultimately average values are computed using the probability density $\vert\psi(x)\vert^2$, two states like $\psi(x)$ and $e^{i\alpha}\psi(x)$ that differ only by an overall phase will have the same probability density and are thus *equivalent* from the perspective of the theory.

In your specific case, the two states differ by an overall sign that goes away in $\vert \psi(x)\vert^2$.

Comment: So, I can say that in general two states are the same only if they have the same energies and the same probability density?
By the way, sorry I can't vote this answer is useful, because I don't have enough points :)

Comment: @Y.Jack They might have the same energy but still be different states.  For instance, in the hydrogen atom, there are many different states with the same energy.

Comment: I know, that is why I added "same energies and the same probability density". is it still wrong?

Comment: It is incorrect.  The fact that they have the same energies is unrelated to the probability densities.  Two different states will have different probability densities; two states with the same energy can be different.  However, two states with different energies cannot have the same probability densities.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, because to me you are saying the same as me:
lets say:

A) Two states have the same energy.

B) Two states have the same probability densities.

If two state applies  A) *and* B), then both state are the same?

Comment: No.  Two states can have the same energy but different probability densities.  Hydrogen states with $E=-13.6/4$eVs are example of different states with different probability densities but the same energy.

Answer (score 2):

In Quantum Mechanics, what is really important are rays in Hilbert space, that is a set of nonzero vectors, differing by just a complex scalar factor; any of them can be chosen as a state vector to represent the ray and thus the state.
A unit vector is usually picked, but its phase factor can be chosen freely anyway.

(Nevertheless, such factors are important when state vectors are added together to form a superposition)